# Using OData endpoint for GET but performance is battered, the SQL Profiler shows parameters that are not understood

Tags: c#, sql, linq, odata

I am trying to debug the response time for GET OData endpoint which is greater than 100ms, checked to see the Db call call and used SQL Profiler for the Linq query that is executed as follows:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    @p__linq__1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[PreferenceTypeId] AS [PreferenceTypeId], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[Value] AS [Value], 
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C2], 
    N''PreferenceType'' AS [C3], 
    @p__linq__2 AS [C4], 
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C5], 
    cast(0 as bit) AS [C6]
    FROM  [User].[UserPreferences] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [User].[PreferencesTypes] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PreferenceTypeId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__2 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=18061,@p__linq__1=N'8cdf4006-8a93-43f1-9153-db10c7f5653f',@p__linq__2=N'8cdf4006-8a93-43f1-9153-db10c7f5653f'
```

The endpoint URL is as follows:

```
?$expand=preferencetype&$filter=userid eq 18061
```

Don't seem to understand the @p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__2 nvarchar(4000). Nowhere is my Db models or the Db itself have I set nvarchar(4000) rather they're nvarchar(500) on 2 occasions only.

What are/ Why are

1. The extra parameters?
2. The parameters being set to max i.e. 4000?

Comment: OData itself generates weird projections and In addition to weak EF6 LINQ translator - that's what you have.

Comment: Ideally LINQ translator has to do not return constant values via SQL (if it is. possible). Not sure but EF Core should not have such problem.

Answer (score 0):

this happen because entity framework send query values to DB only with parameters and never inside the query as string. this is why when you put on your WHERE clause on the lambda expression (or linq to sql) values they changed to params.

you can see the vlues at the end of your code:

```
@p__linq__0=18061,
@p__linq__1=N'8cdf4006-8a93-43f1-9153-db10c7f5653f',
@p__linq__2=N'8cdf4006-8a93-43f1-9153-db10c7f5653f'
```

Comment: That's understandable thanks but for my Odata query, I only have a condition on the Id. The 2nd and 3rd linq parameters are not part of the condition.

Comment: they are part of the select. can you add your code? as i wrote entity framework don't pass string to the server only parameters. so if you put c# variable they change it to parameter and pass the data. this prevent any option to corrupt your DB.